# Why doesn't vue-signature-pad work in a modal?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, signaturepad

I am currently using the following library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-signature-pad which has the following example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5qjp3oqv4

I am applying it as the example, but I have it in a modal:

```
<v-dialog v-model="canvasVehiculo" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
         <v-card>
         <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
         <v-btn icon dark @click="canvasVehiculo = false">
          <v-icon>close</v-icon>
         </v-btn>
         <v-toolbar-title>Seleccionar partes del vehiculo:</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn dark flat @click="undo">Deshacer</v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-list three-line subheader>
        <v-subheader></v-subheader>            
        <VueSignaturePad
         id="signature"
         width="100%"
         height="450px"
         ref="signaturePad"
        />
   </v-list>
 </v-card>

<script>
import VueSignature from 'vue-signature-pad'; //Unicamente lo importo
</script>
<style scoped>
#signature {
  border: double 3px transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url('imagen.png');
  background-size: 900px 456px; 
  background-position: center;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
</style>
```

If I use it outside of the modal, it works correctly; but in the modal, to make it work, I must modify the size of the screen 
(for example, by using the DevTools' `Toggle device toolbar` to see the responsive form).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open DevTools and look at the `canvas` element. At first you will see its width and height (not width and height styles) is set to `0` then resize the window you will see width and height are change to some values and it works.

At [VueSignaturePad.js](https://github.com/neighborhood999/vue-signature-pad/blob/master/src/components/VueSignaturePad.js). look at `resizeCanvas` methods

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
```

When `v-dialog` is mounted and then `VueSignaturePad` is mounted. The `resizeCanvas` is call once at `mounted` and at that moment somehow the canvas has no width and height (due to its parent) so it sets those values to `0`. After you resize the window it will call again and update those values.

One way to solve this is just call `resizeCanvas` after its parent finish render.

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.signaturePad.resizeCanvas();
})
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rm4626oy4).

Note: The `resizeCanvas` is not the official method.

Answer (score 21):

Its due to dialog not having width & height yet when the canvas is initializing within it, to solve it, you can pass the resizeCanvas event call to the options of the component:

```
<VueSignaturePad
    id="signature"
    width="100%"
    height="200px"
    ref="signaturePad"
    :options="{onBegin: () => {$refs.signaturePad.resizeCanvas()}}"
/>
```

Comment: IMO this should be marked as an answer, better practice

Comment: This should be marked are the right answer! Thanks @eselskas

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas is not being resized as the element does not exist when its initialized.
If you are using vue-botostrap:
add static and lazy props to the modal. That will solve it.

```
<b-modal static lazy >
```